# Discord.js How to mention message author?

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

I searched a lot for the answer, but I didn't find and/or understand it.
How can I mention the message author in this code?

It just says:

> ${user.username} pong

But I want:

> @(msg-author-username) pong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's actually a really simple function that's already in the `discord.js` module that provides that to you.

Instead of writing `${user.username} pong`, you can do `message.reply('pong')`... however this formats it into `@user, pong`. So it adds a comma.

An alternate method is to simply do `message.channel.send('<@' + message.author.id + '> pong');` in order to not use the comma. But I prefer `message.reply` simply because it's a lot less typing to deal with lol.

To align the alt method closer to your code, you could consider setting `user` to `message.author` rather than `message.author.name` since that's just the nickname object instead.
Then, from that, you can simply do `` message.channel.send(`<@${user.id}> pong`); ``

So it should look like:

```js
const user = message.author;
return message.channel.send(`<@${user.id}> pong`);
```

Another method:

```js
const user = message.author;
return message.channel.send(`${user} pong`);
```

Hope this helps!